# ASP.Net Identity with Database-first approach

Tags: asp.net-identity

We are implementing ASP.Net Identity with Database-first approach.

Now, every time we run Scaffold-DbContext command, we need to make below change in the auto-generated AppDbContext class due to Database-first approach:

** Inherit AppDbContext from IdentityDbContext instead of DbContext **

We are just in the initial phase of project development having 3-4 developers working on it. We are frequently making changes in the database, so we need to make above change each time.

Is there any solution to avoid this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? There is a CLI option to set which dbcontext class to use.
[image: CLI Options]

Comment: I am already passing context name as AppDbContext while running the Scaffold-DbContext command but the auto generated AppDbContext class inherits from DbContext. I want to inherit it from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> If I update it and run Scaffold-DbContext command again it will overwrite the changes. I want to avoid that.